# Laravel Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Model Doctor

```
class Doctor extends Model
{
    public function addresses() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class);
    }
}
```

Model Address

```
 class Address extends Model
    {
      public function doctors() {
          return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
      }
    }
```

DoctorsController

```
class DoctorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $doctors = Doctor::with('addresses')->get();

        return view('doctors.index',compact('doctors'));
    }
}
```

Blade

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    {{ $doctor->name }}
    @foreach($doctor->addresses as $address)
        {{ $address->city }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

I have an error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I tried to make a relation between Doctor and Address, but it doesn't work. If i try dd($doctor->addresses) i have null.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

does it make sense that a doctor has many addresses and a address has many doctors? basing on your models you do have a many to many relationship between doctors and addresses?

Why not you can do it this way. a doctor has many addresses? so one to many relationship

then your models would be like this way.

Doctor model

```
class Doctor extends Model
{
    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address','DoctorId');// you need to indicate the foreign key if you didn't follow the laravel naming convention
    }
}
```

address model

```
class Address extends Model
{
    public function doctor() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Doctor','DoctorId');// you need to indicate the foriegn key if you didn't follow the Laravel naming convention
      }
}
```

you controller

```
class DoctorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $doctors = Doctor::all();//or Doctor::where('something','=','value')->get();

        return view('doctors.index',compact('doctors'));
    }
}
```

your view

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    {{ $doctor->name }}
    @foreach($doctor->addresses as $address)
        {{ $address->city }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You reference the same class in your relations ("Doctor belongs to Doctor"), that probably cannot work.

Try:

```php
class Doctor extends Model
{
    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
}
 class Address extends Model
    {
      public function doctors() {
          return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class);
      }
    }
```

Comment: now i have "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'addresses.doctor_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from addresses where addresses.doctor_id in

Comment: Well, what is the structure of the `addresses` table? Laravel just assumes the FK is named `CLASS_id` so it "guesses" `doctor_id`. If it is something else you need to provide that using the second argument to `hasMany`, e.g.: `$this->hasMany(Address::class, 'id_of_doctor')` - see also the "One To Many" section in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships